# Problem when using multiple multirow commands in a table

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am trying to create a three columns table with a format 
[like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvzV1.jpg)
Naturally, the description is longer than the name column. Additionally, I want to use \multicolumn command for the example column for aesthetics reason. Here is the code,

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|p {5 cm}|p {5 cm}|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Complex Type} & \multirow{2}{5 cm}{\parbox[c]{5 cm}{This variable type is used to declare a complex number, the real part and also the imaginary part.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Defining a complex number 3.0 + 5.0 i :} \\
             & & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{complex :: a = (3.0, 5.0)} \\
        \hline 
        \multirow{4}{*}{Character Type} & \multirow{4}{4 cm}{This variable type is used to store one character by default. It can be used to store string or multiple characters using the len modifier. The len modifier works exactly the same as kind modifier. The example is on how to declare two variables, var1 for a character and var 2 for a sentence holder.} & character :: var1 \\
             & & character (len = 40) :: var2 \\
             & & var1 = "A" \\
             & & var2 = "How do you turn this on?" \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
```

I apologize if the code is too long. It seems the problem is because the entire row cell's height is not adjusted for the highest cell. It is fixed based on the first column instead. I have tried to try several method and nothing works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use these complicate constructs with `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` just to change the alignment and add line breaks, this can be done much more easily:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|m{5cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{6.2cm}|}
        \hline
        Complex Type &
        This variable type is used to declare a complex number, the real part and also the imaginary part. & 
        Defining a complex number 3.0 + 5.0 i : \linebreak
        complex :: a = (3.0, 5.0) \\
        \hline 
        Character Type & 
        This variable type is used to store one character by default. It can be used to store string or multiple characters using the len modifier. The len modifier works exactly the same as kind modifier. The example is on how to declare two variables, var1 for a character and var 2 for a sentence holder. & 
        character :: var1 \linebreak
        character (len = 40) :: var2 \linebreak
        var1 = "A" \linebreak
        var2 = "How do you turn this on?" \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]